# Winform application picturebox maximizing problem

Tags: c#, winforms

My main task is the design and the creation of my own "Close","Minimize" and "Maximize" button. Also I need to use a line under the buttons.

When I maximize my form, the line does not stretch enough. I added the line with `pictureBox`. I added an image in order to understand my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed with an `anchor`. Usually it is set by default only to up and left. Try to set it on right direction as well

This `anchor` helps exactly in this situation (calculate w/h based on the windows size, and keeps the "proportions" of the view)

More details here : [Microsoft-Anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=netcore-3.1)

[image]

Comment: Also i changed sizeMode of picturebox to StrechImage. Thanks for the help.